# WP7 XNA Framework application requirements

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna, directx

I am having problems debugging a Windows Phone XNA game application. I can build it, but when emulator shows up I get the error:

**The current display adapter does not meet the emulator requirements to run XNA Framework applications.**

I've read many topics on the same issue and in most cases the reason was not good enough graphics card. I don't think that's why I get this error. I would also like to mention that **I can** run Silverlight applications for WP7. Here are some screenshots:

[DxDiag window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xQR5.png)

[DxDiag display window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzrtM.png)

I also downloaded latest ATI Catalyst package today but it didn't help. Any ideas?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

This is what I have just found out:

[image: Hardware virtualization]

Is this maybe causing a problem. I am not sure because the error says the issue with display adapter.

Comment: see if this will help: http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/support/configure-bios.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could try to override the requirements check, however make sure you backup your registry and you are on your own if something goes wrong:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\XDE XNAEnableGPU = 1 (REG_DWORD)
```

Comment: I don't have such registry key. :/

Comment: did you reboot after install of the SDK? also do you have any other versions installed like 5.x or 6.x?

Comment: Looks like I didn't have latest SDK version, it now works fine, thanks :)